# Is there anything like a subst_tac rule in Isabelle?

Tags: substitution, isabelle

I have the lemma

```
lemma ex1_variable: "(∃x. ∀z. x = y z) = (∃!x. ∀z. x = y z)"
```

and I have an intermediate statement in a proof

```
"∀a. ∃P. ∀z. P = Q z a"
```

I would like to show

```
"∀a. ∃!P. ∀z. P = Q z a".
```

I cannot use `by (rule ex1_variable)` directly because of the `∀a`. However, I feel like it should be possible to use something like the `subst` method e.g.

```
from `∀a. ∃P. ∀z. P = Q z a` have "∀a. ∃!P. ∀z. P = Q z a"
  by (subst_tac ?x="P" and ?y="λx. Q x a" and ?z="z" in ex1_variable)
```

so that `ex1_variable` is substituted in the present goal but only after having been instantiated. This particular example doesn't work, but is there anything along similar lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly instantiate the lemma `ex1_variable`, higher-order unification will do that for you. And since `ex1_variable` is an equality statement, you can actually use plain `subst` to prove replace the instance of the left-hand side with the instantiated right-hand side. But you have to tell `subst` to look in the assumptions since this is where the left-hand side instance occurs in your subgoal. So the following should work:

```
lemma ex1_variable: "(∃x. ∀z. x = y z) = (∃!x. ∀z. x = y z)" sorry

notepad begin
  fix Q
  have "∀a. ∃P. ∀z. P = Q z a" sorry
  then have "∀a. ∃!P. ∀z. P = Q z a"
    by(subst (asm) ex1_variable)
end
```

Alternatively, you can flip the sides of the theorem around and apply `subst` to the conclusion:

```
by(subst ex1_variable[symmetric])
```